# Scala: defining a map via a list of integers

Tags: r, scala, functional-programming

Coming to Scala from R (complete newbie).

Say I have two lists:

```
val index  = List(0,0,1,0,1)
val a      = List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Then `index` can define a natural map from `a` to `b: List[List[Int]]`:

```
1 -> b(0)
2 -> b(0)
3 -> b(1)
4 -> b(0)
5 -> b(1)
```

So that:

```
b = List(List(1,2,4), List(3,5))
```

In general, given `index` and `a`, what is the most natural way to create `b` in Scala?

e.g. in R I could for example write:

```
run_map <- function(index, a) {
  map <- function(data, i) {
    data[[i]] <- a[which(index == i)]
    data
  }
  Reduce(map, unique(index), list())
}
```

Cheers for any help!

Comment: What will be the contents of `b`?

Comment: Just included contents of `b`. Hopefully it is now clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want one list to contain the index and the other list to contain the values then you would `zip` them together:

```
val myMap = (a zip b).toMap
```

where `a` contains the index and `b` the values.

However, if there's duplicate indexes then you would want to do the following:

```
for{
  (i, list) <- (a zip b) groupBy (_._1)
} yield (i, list map (_._2))
```

wherein you're zipping, grouping by the index and then mapping over the values in the list. That created list contains both the index and value as a tuple.

Answer (score 4):

0) Given:

```
val index  = List(0,0,1,0,1)
val a      = List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Here is an "iterative" way to arrive at the solution:

1) "Zip" 2 lists together to produce a list of pairs:

```
index.zip(a)
```

result:

```
List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,1), (0,2), (1,3), (0,4), (1,5))
```

2) Group by first element of the pair in the list.

`index.zip(a).groupBy(_._1)`

result:

```
Map[Int,List[(Int, Int)]] = Map(1 -> List((1,3), (1,5)), 0 -> List((0,1), (0,2), (0,4)))
```

3) Remove redundant index by projecting only second element from each pair in the list `v`:

```
index.zip(a).groupBy(_._1).map{ case (i, v) => (i, v.map(_._2)) }
```

result:

```
Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(3, 5), 0 -> List(1, 2, 4))
```